# sql trigger IF statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have the following trigger created for when the value of a specific column is detected:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trCompletedDate] ON [dbo].[Record]
FOR UPDATE AS BEGIN
IF(UPDATE(Completed))

UPDATE Record SET Completed_Date=DATEADD(hh, 7, GETDATE())
FROM Record 
INNER JOIN Inserted ON Record.[ID]= Inserted.[ID]
WHERE Record.Completed = 1
END
```

Which works fine but I would like to add an IF statement to change the value of Completed_Date to another value when Record.Completed = 0.

I am just unsure of how the syntax goes.

Comment: So can you try to add an `IF` block ?

Comment: that's it, I just don't know what the syntax for it is.

Comment: You can easily find the syntax with a search engine...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE Record SET Completed_Date = 
CASE WHEN Record.Completed = 1 THEN
   DATEADD(hh, 7, GETDATE())
ELSE
   --Somethin else
END
FROM Record 
INNER JOIN Inserted ON Record.[ID]= Inserted.[ID]
```

Comment: Need to remove the `WHERE Record.Completed = 1`.

Comment: yes I have done that already.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [CASE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) statement:

```
UPDATE Record 
SET Completed_Date = 
    CASE Record.Completed WHEN 1 THEN DATEADD(hh, 7, GETDATE())
                          WHEN 0 THEN SOMETHINGELSE END
FROM Record 
INNER JOIN Inserted ON Record.[ID]= Inserted.[ID]
WHERE Record.Completed IN (0,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trCompletedDate] ON [dbo].[Record]
FOR UPDATE AS BEGIN
IF(UPDATE(Completed))

UPDATE Record SET 
    Completed_Date=if Record.Completed=0 then <othervalue> 
                   else DATEADD(hh, 7, GETDATE()) endif
FROM Record 
INNER JOIN Inserted ON Record.[ID]= Inserted.[ID]
WHERE Record.Completed = 1
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trCompletedDate] ON [dbo].[Record]
FOR UPDATE AS BEGIN
IF(UPDATE(Completed))

UPDATE Record SET Completed_Date=
    CASE Record.Completed
        WHEN 1 THEN DATEADD(hh, 7, GETDATE())
        WHEN 0 THEN GETDATE()
    END
FROM Record 
INNER JOIN Inserted ON Record.[ID]= Inserted.[ID]
END
```